# ERROR after change data_directory of PostgreSQL in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu 16.04; PostgreSQL: 10

I want to move the data_directory from default directory to another.

Original Data_directory: ~/var/lib/postgresql/main

I have rsync the data_directory to media/my_name/HHD/postgreql/10/main by

```
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql/main  media/my_name/HHD/
```

and also edit ~/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
to change the path.

---

After restart postgresql, I executed "psql" and the error come out as below:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such data or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have changed user but there was the same error msg.

I have also tried:

```
sudo ln -s /media/vierylin/HHD/postgresql/10/main/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

it still failed.

After recover data_directory path to original directory, the error msg disappear.

How can I fix the /.s.PGSQL.5432